# Multi-module Gradle support in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, sonarqube

**Question: When will the IntelliJ SonarQube plugin support multi-module Gradle projects?**

I asked this very question in the SonarQube user mailing group (2015-04-07) and received the reply that support for multi-module Gradle projects was to be implemented "the next sprint". Since stackoverflow has been designated the new preferred way to address these type of questions I thought it appropriate to gather information about this feature request here.

---

**Steps to reproduce**

In IntelliJ IDEA:

- Settings/Plugins: Install the SonarQube IntelliJ plugin (official, not the community version)
- Settings/Other Settings/SonarQube: Configure the plugin to connect to the SonarQube instance
- Project tree: Right-click the project root folder and select "Associate with SonarQube..."
- Select the correct project fetched from SonarQube (may require searching)

**Expected outcome**

The project is successfully associated

**Actual outcome**

Error message in the SonarQube plugin console: "Only multi-module Maven projects are supported for now".

**My setup**

- SonarQube, version 4.5.4 LTS
- IntelliJ IDEA, version 14.1.4
- "SonarQube plugin for IntelliJ IDEA", version 1.1

Comment: Does your question fit in the scheme  "For questions like:
How do I… ?
I got this error, why ?
… on topics like:
installation,
configuration,
unexpected behaviour,
migration issue,
…etc."?

Comment: dunni: Probably not. Where would you ask this question? There is no other channel for me to ask but on Stackoverflow as far as I know

Comment: SonarSource has a bugtracker for that: http://jira.sonarsource.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Yes, which is not public

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an expectation on an upcoming feature rather than a real problem/question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the issue tracker and found the task that will fix this problem. Since I don't have an account, I cannot up-vote it though:

http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGRADL-5